# How long does an RDS storage conversion take?

Tags: rds

I have an RDS PostgreSQL instance with 500MB on magnetic disk. To speed it up, I applied a conversion to SSD. However, after 24 hours, the RDS console is still showing that it's "modifying". Is that normal? How long should a conversion from magnetic to solid state storage take?

Comment: Did you hit "apply immediately"? If you didn't, it'll wait until the next weekly maintenance window, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I applied immediately.

Comment: I'd open an AWS Support case, then.

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved? I'm getting a similar problem with Magnetic to SSD conversion.